# How to set velocity of moving balls to a range of speeds (Java)

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

I'm writing a program that deals with ball/particle movements. I want to program the logic so "hot" balls move between 4cm and 6cm per sec, while "cold" balls move between 2cm and 4cm per sec. How can I use the pixels per cm (113/2.54), where 113 is my screen resolution per inch, to set the velocities?

I'm just using a fixed number for the vx and vy values for the balls.

This is my Ball constructor

```
public Ball(Side s, Color color) { //Side character used to determine if ball should spawn on left or right side.

        //makeRandom method gives positive or negative direction for each ball
        if (color == Color.RED){
            this.vx = 8 * makeRandom(); 
            this.vy = 8 * makeRandom();
        } else {
            this.vx = 5 * makeRandom();
            this.vy = 5 * makeRandom();
        }

        speed = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.vx, 2)+Math.pow(this.vy, 2));

        //position is randomized for each ball 
        if(s == Side.LEFT) {
            this.x = leftSideBallX + (int) (50 * Math.random());
            this.y = leftSideBallY + (int) (50 * Math.random()); 
        } else {
            this.x = rightSideBallX + (int) (50 * Math.random());
            this.y = rightSideBallY + (int) (50 * Math.random());
        }

    }
```

and this is my game loop

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        running = true;

        addParticlesToVector();

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        while (running) {

            start = System.nanoTime();

            gameUpdate();
            this.repaint();

            leftTemp.setText("Temperature: " + df.format(lTemp));
            rightTemp.setText("Temperature: " + df.format(rTemp));

            elapsed = (start - System.nanoTime());
            wait = targetTime - elapsed/1000000;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want the velocity to be in a range (rather than the x and y velocities) then you'll need to separately generate speed and direction. At the moment you generate the x and y speeds independently which will give you a much larger range of combined velocities. This needs some basic trig.

I suggest keeping the model's values separate from the user interface considerations (such as converting from cms to #pixels. I also suggest encapsulating your concept of heat.

```
class Ball {
    private float angle;
    private float speed;

    public Ball(Random random, Heat heat) {
        this.angle = random.nextFloat(Math.PI * 2);
        this.speed = heat.randomSpeed(random);
    }

    public float xVelocity() {
        return speed * Math.cos(angle);
    }

    public float yVelocity() {
        return speed * Math.sin(angle);
    }
}

class ScreenConverter {
    private static final float PIXELS_PER_CM = 113f/2.54f;

    public float pixelsToDistance(int pixels) {
        return pixels * PIXELS_PER_CM;
    }

    public int distanceToPixels(float distanceInCMs) {
        return int(distanceInCM / PIXELS_PER_CM);
    }
}
```